# RadioButton implement for Default activity?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I will appreciate if someone help me with this code:

1-  I have got 3 RadioButton for 3 activities English.class, France.class, Italian.class
for user Select Default Language on app start. can someone help me how to implement that..?

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

private RadioGroup radioLaGroup;
private RadioButton radioLaButton;
private CheckBox chk_clear;
private Button btnDisplay;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.settings);

addListenerOnButton();
addListenerClear();

}


 public void addListenerOnButton() {

radioLaGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioLa);
btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
        int selectedId = radioLaGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioLaButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

    }

});

}
}
```

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: is preferences initialized? and where is `isFirstTime` called?

Comment: on another activity called help.class

Comment: ok is preferences  initialized in help.class and can you post the stack trace?

Comment: my problem is when tick a CheckBox do not show help again i mean not cleared preferences...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by change :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", 0);
```

to this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("help", 0);
```

thanks Raghunandan for your replay....

but still i have Not solved RadioButton neeeeed help ..... please

Comment: Explain your problem a little bit so that I can help

Answer (score 0):

Use Switch inside the onClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = null;
    int selectedId = radioLaGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    switch(selectedId) {
        case R.id.frenchRadio:
            intent = new Intent(this, French.class);
            break;
        case R.id.italianRadio:
            intent = new Intent(this, Italian.class);
            break;
        case R.id.englishRadio:
            intent = new Intent(this, French.class);
            break;
    }
    if(intent != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }   
}
```